# Android text view - Add some constant (non cropping) text to the end of text

Tags: android, android-layout

I am trying to make an android textview to display a title and the distance. My code is as follows

```
<TextView android:id="@+id/name" android:textSize="15dip"
android:ellipsize="end" android:maxLines="2"
android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
```

The text in the text view will be cropped automatically after filling 2 lines. If I append the distance with the text. distance also got cropped. I need to keep the title cropped, but not the distance.

For example

```
"This is title line 1 
and this is title lin... (2 Mi)"
```

Comment: I did this by measuring the size of a character (using avg) and manually cropped my main text, and appended the distance text to it.

avgCharSize = txtName.getPaint().measureText("iw.H012()R")/10.0f; // As my text contains chars, symbols and numbers

Answer (score 0):

Keep two TextViews adjacent to each other.  The 1st TextView should be dynamic, 2nd should be constant "(2 Mi)"
This way you can easily maintain it.  The coding solution to this will need to

1. Calculate available width
2. Calculate the textwidth covered by the entire string
3. If value of step 2 > value of step 1, subtract a substring

this sounds like an inefficient way to do it

Answer (score 0):

You can give fix length of text to be shown by setting in xml

```
android:maxLength="50"
```

Then coding side,

```
String str = "Your String";
String constantStr = "2 Mi";
if(str.length()>43)
{
    str = str.subString(0,42)+"..."+constantStr;
}
else
{
    str = str + " " + constantStr; 
}
tv.setText(str);
```

Comment: This sounds good, but will this make difference in different devices with different screen sizes? I am trying to find the number of characters my textview can display per line (may be different in different devices).

Comment: I think the number of characters will work on any screen size, althought I never tested